# How can I send datas to the database without use inputs to get values?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying send some informations to the database through the buttons:

```
//index.blade

<button class="btn btn-primary">START CASHIER</button>

<button class="btn btn-danger">CLOSE CASHIER</button>
```

When I click on the button START should trigger a function that send two datas to the database [start and status] see my database bellow:

```
id | start | last | status | updated_at | created_at | active
```

my CashierController I tried this:

```
public function insertData(){
    $date = date('d-m-Y H:i');

    DB::table('cashier')->insert([
        'start' => DB::raw('INET_ATON(\''.$date.'\')'),
    ]);

    return view('admin/cashier/index')
        ->with('date',$date);

}
```

my model:

```
protected $table = 'cashier';

public $timestamps = false;

protected $fillable = [
    'id','start','last','status','updated_at','created_at','active'
];
```

my route web php:

```
//================================Cashier=================================//
Route::get('/admin/cashier', 'CashierController@index');
Route::post('/admin/cashier', 'CashierController@insertData')->name('type.store');
```

I already tried to use link and pass the route in href:

```
<a href="{{action('CashierController@insertData')}}">START CASHIER</a>
```

I really have no idea if this is possible, because i didn't create a CRUD.

I want to know how to send datas to the database via a button by calling a function from the controller. Is it possible? There are others solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use form and submit button, like below snippet

```
<form action="{{action('CashierController@insertData')}}" method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">START CASHIER</button>
</form>
```